# What´s the easiest way for a user authentication in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

does anybody have a manuel that describes the steps to create an anonymous
user authentication in SharePoint 2010 (Website for the internet with no authentication). 
For editing an admin has to log in 
with forms authentication. Can I hold the admin somewhere in the web.config with
membership provider ? Or do I need to install SQL Server somewhere for that task ?

Thanx a lot.
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Ah - you need SQL Server installed somewhee ANYWAY - SharePoint makes heavy use of SQL Server.

Comment: that´s right, but I mean for hold the admin with his password. In asp.net it was possible to save them in the web.config.

Comment: What for? NO snipping around here, but the SharePoint databases are a "must" anyway.

Comment: Hi,
I have the SQL-Server for my SharePoint that´s right.
But I want to use a membership provider for forms authentication, without holding the users in a SQL-Server. In ASP.NET you can configure them in the web.config. Is this possible in SHarePoint ?

Thanx
Stephan

Comment: Won't work. The user is more in sharepoint than just an id - there is a provile etc. attached. So, even if you log in externally (possible, look it up when yo ucreate a new site collection) the user record will be created as proxy in sharepoint.

Comment: But I can link the user with a a membership provider. There I can create a new user and the webadmin can give the rights for a page. I´m just interessed in the configuration of the membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that *any* valid ASP.NET membership provider should work with SharePoint, so in theory you should be able to write your own XML-based or text-based provider and store the admin username and password there.

But it's too much work and a bit risky. And in all honesty I would personally avoid trying anything like that since SharePoint is a complex enough behemoth by itself.

Since you only want an admin to be able to modify the website, it's probably a lot easier to just use the Active Directory provider and create a user in AD for the admin if one doesn't already exist.

HTH